# Guidance with labview webservice

Tags: labview

I have a VI which reads data from a IMU unit and displays data via a graph. I want to do a web app version of it with javascript.
Would I have to extend the same VI as a new copy under web services to perform control from the browser or use a shared variable to convert the data into JSON and send to the browser for visualization

Arigatou ;)

Answer (score 0):

Arigatou,

It is not entirely clear from your question what exactly your application needs to do, but if you are going to interact with your application via a browser, than you are going to probably want to use web services (although [web sockets](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-40572) looks promising).

Based on your quick description, you will want a web service that *streams* data from the server to a client (i.e. the browser).  You have several choices on how you send the data back - JSON is fairly compact and yet still descriptive.  Be conscious of *how* you send data back as you will be sending it via some kind of ascii string.  You also may want to look at how to set the header on the server side to handle [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) requests.

The final piece of this puzzle on the server side is how to get the data from your main application to the web service.  For this, you can use any method that allows application instances to communicate - queues, notifiers, FGVs, DVRs, etc., etc.

Once you get the data out there though, there is a ton of ways to display it and you enter a whole new realm of development.  I would encourage you to take a look at the [NI Web Development Community](https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/web-services) for more on getting started.  And then once you have got the basics, use SO for asking questions concerning client side development.  This community is awesome!  Cheers, Matt